# use a saved trained model to predict on new dataset

Tags: python, theano

I am using theano, sklearn and numpy in Python. I found this code for saving my trained network and predict on my new dataset in this link https://github.com/lzhbrian/RBM-DBN-theano-DL4J/blob/master/src/theano/code/logistic_sgd.py. the part of the code I am using is this :

```
"""
An example of how to load a trained model and use it
to predict labels.
"""
def predict():
# load the saved model
classifier = pickle.load(open('best_model.pkl'))

# compile a predictor function
predict_model = theano.function(
inputs=[classifier.input],
outputs=classifier.y_pred)

# We can test it on some examples from test test
dataset='mnist.pkl.gz'
datasets = load_data(dataset)
test_set_x, test_set_y = datasets[2]
test_set_x = test_set_x.get_value()

predicted_values = predict_model(test_set_x[:10])
print("Predicted values for the first 10 examples in test set:")
print(predicted_values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
sgd_optimization_mnist()
```

The code for the neural network model  I want to save and load and predict with is https://github.com/aseveryn/deep-qa. I could save and load the model with cPickle but I continuously get errors in `# compile a predictor function` part:

```
predict_model = theano.function(inputs=[classifier.input],outputs=classifier.y_pred)
```

Actually I am not certain what I need to put in the inputs according to my code. Which one is right?

```
inputs=[main.predict_prob_batch.batch_iterator],  outputs=test_nnet.layers[-1].
y_pred)

inputs=[predict_prob_batch.batch_iterator],
outputs=test_nnet.layers[-1].y_pred)

inputs=[MiniBatchIteratorConstantBatchSize.dataset],
outputs=test_nnet.layers[-1].y_pred)

inputs=[
sgd_trainer.MiniBatchIteratorConstantBatchSize.dataset],
outputs=test_nnet.layers[-1].y_pred)
```

or none of them???

Each of them I tried I got the errors:

> ImportError: No module named MiniBatchIteratorConstantBatchSize

or

> NameError: global name 'predict_prob_batch' is not defined

I would really appreciate if you could help me.
I also used these commands for running the code but still the errors.

```
python -c 'from run_nnet import predict; from sgd_trainer import MiniBatchIteratorConstantBatchSize; from MiniBatchIteratorConstantBatchSize import dataset; print predict()'


python -c 'from run_nnet import predict; from sgd_trainer import *; from MiniBatchIteratorConstantBatchSize import dataset; print predict()'
```

Thank you and let me know please if you know a better way to predict for new dataset on the loaded trained model.